# I have to make a pyramid of letters in the middle of the screen i am able to print the pyramide but can not seem to get the alphabet and to go in

Tags: python, palindrome, alphabet

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rpBR.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZH04N.png

def full_pyramid(rows):

```
print('\nFull pyramid...\n')




for i in range(rows):



    print(' '*(rows-i-1) + '*'*(2*i+1))
```

string =" "

reversed_string = string[::-1]

result_string = " ".join(string)

for a in range(0 ,25):

```
result_string += chr(ord('a')+a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it

Python 3.x :

```
def pyramid(rows):
    s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    for i in range(rows, 0, -1):
        for j in range(i):
            print(' ', end='')
        for k in range(rows-i):
            print(s[k], end='')
        for m in range(rows-i, -1, -1):
            print(s[m], end='')
        print()

pyramid(15)
```

Python 2.x :

```
def pyramid(rows):
    s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    for i in range(rows, 0, -1):
        for j in range(i):
            print(' '),
        for k in range(rows-i):
            print(s[k]),
        for m in range(rows-i, -1, -1):
            print(s[m]),
        print('')

pyramid(15)
```

Comment: wow, u guys are really grreat,i see know, u have to put in the whole alhabet first as a variable,thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
import string

rows = 26
for i in range(rows):
    row = string.ascii_letters[i]
    for c in range(i-1,-1,-1):
        outside = string.ascii_letters[c]
        row = '%s%s%s' % (outside, row, outside)
    space = ' '*(rows-i)
    row = '%s%s%s' % (space, row, space)
    print(row)
```